# What can I do if the data I want to write to a Json file is not structured correctly?

Tags: python, json, api

I'm trying to retrieve data using an API and Python, and then save it in a Json file.

Unfortunately, the API returns very poorly structured data, so I can't search the file programmatically.

The data then looks something like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    [
      [],
      null
    ],
    [
      [
        {
          "1. symbol": "YI",
          "2. name": "111 Inc.",
          "3. type": "Equity",
          "4. region": "United States",
          "5. marketOpen": "09:30",
          "6. marketClose": "16:00",
          "7. timezone": "UTC-05",
          "8. currency": "USD",
          "9. matchScore": "0.3636"
        }
      ],
      null
    ],
    [
      [
        {
          "1. symbol": "2GB.DEX",
          "2. name": "2G Energy AG",
          "3. type": "Equity",
          "4. region": "XETRA",
          "5. marketOpen": "08:00",
          "6. marketClose": "20:00",
          "7. timezone": "UTC+02",
          "8. currency": "EUR",
          "9. matchScore": "0.5714"
        },
        {
          "1. symbol": "2GL.FRK",
          "2. name": "Gaming and Leisure Properties Inc.",
          "3. type": "Equity",
          "4. region": "Frankfurt",
          "5. marketOpen": "08:00",
          "6. marketClose": "20:00",
          "7. timezone": "UTC+02",
          "8. currency": "EUR",
          "9. matchScore": "0.5714"
        }
      ],
      null
    ]
  ]
}
```

I manage to filter out the None before it is saved, but the brackets remain and destroy the structure.

Does anyone know how I can get this data well structured? I'm using Python 3.8

Comment: What do you consider to be "well structured"? What have you tried to get the data to that desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is definitely a pattern there.
Basically, the data's structure is as follows:

```
{
   "data":[ 
        [[<values you look for>], null],
        [[<values you look for>], null]
    ]
}
```

It is unclear from the questions what is expected to be where `null` is, so i'll ignore that part.

To extract the rest, this wiil do the job:

```
flat_data = []
for data in response['data']:
    flat_data += data[0]
```

You will get a flat list of dicts.

Comment: I don't know why there is this null, that was my problem. And I didn't see the pattern, so thank you Sir :)

Answer (score 1):

Your json structure is perfecty fine, just use the `json` library to process data correctly:

```
import json

data = """{
  "data": [
    [
      [],
      null
    ],
    [
      [
        {
          "1. symbol": "YI",
          "2. name": "111 Inc.",
          "3. type": "Equity",
          "4. region": "United States",
          "5. marketOpen": "09:30",
          "6. marketClose": "16:00",
          "7. timezone": "UTC-05",
          "8. currency": "USD",
          "9. matchScore": "0.3636"
        }
      ],
      null
    ],
    [
      [
        {
          "1. symbol": "2GB.DEX",
          "2. name": "2G Energy AG",
          "3. type": "Equity",
          "4. region": "XETRA",
          "5. marketOpen": "08:00",
          "6. marketClose": "20:00",
          "7. timezone": "UTC+02",
          "8. currency": "EUR",
          "9. matchScore": "0.5714"
        },
        {
          "1. symbol": "2GL.FRK",
          "2. name": "Gaming and Leisure Properties Inc.",
          "3. type": "Equity",
          "4. region": "Frankfurt",
          "5. marketOpen": "08:00",
          "6. marketClose": "20:00",
          "7. timezone": "UTC+02",
          "8. currency": "EUR",
          "9. matchScore": "0.5714"
        }
      ],
      null
    ]
  ]
}"""

data_json = json.loads(data)
```

**Output**

```
{'data': [[[], None],
  [[{'1. symbol': 'YI',
     '2. name': '111 Inc.',
     '3. type': 'Equity',
     '4. region': 'United States',
     '5. marketOpen': '09:30',
     '6. marketClose': '16:00',
     '7. timezone': 'UTC-05',
     '8. currency': 'USD',
     '9. matchScore': '0.3636'}],
   None],
  [[{'1. symbol': '2GB.DEX',
     '2. name': '2G Energy AG',
     '3. type': 'Equity',
     '4. region': 'XETRA',
     '5. marketOpen': '08:00',
     '6. marketClose': '20:00',
     '7. timezone': 'UTC+02',
     '8. currency': 'EUR',
     '9. matchScore': '0.5714'},
    {'1. symbol': '2GL.FRK',
     '2. name': 'Gaming and Leisure Properties Inc.',
     '3. type': 'Equity',
     '4. region': 'Frankfurt',
     '5. marketOpen': '08:00',
     '6. marketClose': '20:00',
     '7. timezone': 'UTC+02',
     '8. currency': 'EUR',
     '9. matchScore': '0.5714'}],
   None]]}
```